# get livedata response from integrated retrofit with RxJava

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, android-livedata

i want to get Livedata response from Retrofit integrated with RxJava for call APIs.
I know that RxJava response is stream and could not put it in Livedata directly.So thanks for any help.

Here is a sample code for integrated Retrofit with RxJava.
how can i replace Observable with Livedata.

```
class GitHubRxService {

   private GitHubRxApi gitHubApi;

   GitHubRxService() {
       Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
         .baseUrl("https://api.github.com/")
         .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
         .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
         .build();

       gitHubApi = retrofit.create(GitHubRxApi.class);
   }

   Observable<String> getTopContributors(String userName) {
       return gitHubApi.listRepos(userName)
         .flatMapIterable(x -> x)
         .flatMap(repo -> gitHubApi.listRepoContributors(userName, repo.getName()))
         .flatMapIterable(x -> x)
         .filter(c -> c.getContributions() > 100)
         .sorted((a, b) -> b.getContributions() - a.getContributions())
         .map(Contributor::getName)
         .distinct();
   }
}
```

Comment: If you replace Observable with Single, then you should be able to post a response into a LiveData.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in this way:

1. Specify `MutableLiveData` instace in your class
2. Create method to provide it
3. Post value to `liveData` when your `Observable` returns value
4. Do not forget to dispose your observables
5. **After all I advice you to use Repository for it**

**Your code:**

```java
class GitHubRxService {

    private GitHubRxApi gitHubApi;
    private MutableLiveData<String> liveData = new MutableLiveData();
    private CompositeDisposable disposables = new CompositeDisposable();
    private GitHubRxService() {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://api.github.com/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build();

        gitHubApi = retrofit.create(GitHubRxApi.class);
    }

    public LiveData<String> getLiveData() {
        return liveData;
    }

    void getTopContributors(String userName) {
        Disposable d = gitHubApi.listRepos(userName)
                .flatMapIterable(x -> x)
                .flatMap(repo -> gitHubApi.listRepoContributors(userName, repo.getName()))
                .flatMapIterable(x -> x)
                .filter(c -> c.getContributions() > 100)
                .sorted((a, b) -> b.getContributions() - a.getContributions())
                .map(Contributor::getName)
                .distinct()
                .subscribe(
                        result -> {
                            liveData.postValue(result);
                        },
                        e -> {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        },
                        () -> {
                            Log.d("Done")
                        }
                );
        disposables.add(d)
    }

    public void dispose(){
        disposables.dispose();
    }

}
```

Comment: Nice example! ;) However, why did you advise to use a repository instead? ViewModel allows data to survive configuration changes so if we use your solution we can have the best of both worlds: data that is constantly updated and saved in case of configuration changes. Or did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered having a Repository with LiveData property in it and setting its value from the call?

So in general, when you will be calling a function from the Repository `getTopContributors` - it will return liveData, and make network call. Within the network subscription - you update liveData